# How to disable Jersey's JacksonJsonProvider auto registration so I use my own?

Tags: java, json, jersey, jersey-2.0

I have an `@GET` method that is annotated with a `@Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )`. I'd like to see that call fail when I disable the JSON processing in Jersey, but no matter what I do it continues to generate a JSON output when I access that URL method in the browser.

When I place a breakpoint inside `com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider`'s constructor I see it is being registered when `MessageBodyFactory` is instantiated. In particular, under the line:

```
final Set<MessageBodyReader> mbrs = Providers.getProviders(locator, MessageBodyReader.class);
```

The `JacksonJsonProvider` is discovered even though I disabled all auto-discoveries. As a result I cannot register my own which provides a custom ObjectMapper. The default one is always used instead.

The method looks like this:

```
@GET
@Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
public Status getStatus() {
    return new Status("test");   
}
```

In my application, I make what I believe to be the proper (even an overkill) configurations:

```
public class CustomResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {

public CustomResourceConfig() {

property(CommonProperties.METAINF_SERVICES_LOOKUP_DISABLE, true);
property(CommonProperties.FEATURE_AUTO_DISCOVERY_DISABLE, true);
property(CommonProperties.JSON_PROCESSING_FEATURE_DISABLE, true);
property(CommonProperties.MOXY_JSON_FEATURE_DISABLE, true);

property(ServerProperties.METAINF_SERVICES_LOOKUP_DISABLE, true);
property(ServerProperties.FEATURE_AUTO_DISCOVERY_DISABLE, true);
property(ServerProperties.MOXY_JSON_FEATURE_DISABLE, true);
property(ServerProperties.JSON_PROCESSING_FEATURE_DISABLE, true);

property(ClientProperties.FEATURE_AUTO_DISCOVERY_DISABLE, true);
property(ClientProperties.METAINF_SERVICES_LOOKUP_DISABLE, true);
property(ClientProperties.JSON_PROCESSING_FEATURE_DISABLE, true);

packages("test.package.api");
}
}
```

I have placed the following configs in the web.xml:

```
<servlet>  
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.tracing</param-name>
        <param-value>ALL</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.disableMetainfServicesLookup</param-name>
        <param-value>1</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.disableJsonProcessing</param-name>
        <param-value>1</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.disableMoxyJson</param-name>
        <param-value>1</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.specktro.orchid.deployment.registry.CustomResourceConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
 </servlet>
```

My pom.xml includes the following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Versions are managed by parent POM, but I need to use Jackson 2.3.2, and I'm using Jersey 2.7 (also tried with 2.6, same results).

I also tried registering a `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider` which used my object mapper:

```
register(new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider(objectMapper, null));
```

but that results in two `JacksonJsonProviders` registered: one for my `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider` and one that Jersey registers during initialization and that one gets used so mine is ignored.

How can I get Jersey to use my `JacksonJsonProvider` instead of the default one so I can provide my own `ObjectMapper`?

**UPDATE**
Of course I also tried creating a custom ContextResolver that provides a custom ObjectMapper and registered it, but it is ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem!!
I was not returning an object like normally people do. Instead I was throwing a subclass of WebApplicationException which shows in the client as a JSON:

```
public class ApplicationException extends WebApplicationException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ApplicationException(int errorCode, String message) {
        super(Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(
                    JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode()
                    .put("errorCode", errorCode)
                    .put("errorMessage", message).toString())
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build());
    }

}
```

And THAT is a problem in Jersey... when Jersey handles this exception it does not use the correct Json Provider... instead it registers a default one without my custom settings, and also does not query for the ContextResolver I have registered resulting in an unformatted JSON (I have pretty print turned on on my ObjectMapper).

I opened a bug with Jersey in JIRA:
https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2503

I hope this helps another poor soul trying to handle this case.

Answer (score 0):

It look like this will work. I build a nop JacksonJsonProvider that I register in the JerseyConfig. Here's the code I used to make the nop JacksonJsonProvider:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider;

public class NopJacksonProviderBuilder {

    public static JacksonJaxbJsonProvider nopJacksonJaxbJsonProvider(){
        JacksonJaxbJsonProvider result = new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider(new NopObjectMapper(), null);
        result.checkCanSerialize(true);
        result.checkCanDeserialize(true);
        return result;
    }

    public static JacksonJsonProvider nopJacksonJsonProvider(){
        JacksonJsonProvider result = new JacksonJsonProvider(new NopObjectMapper(), null);
        result.checkCanSerialize(true);
        result.checkCanDeserialize(true);
        return result;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    private static class NopObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper{

        @Override
        public boolean canDeserialize(JavaType type) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean canDeserialize(JavaType type, AtomicReference<Throwable> cause){
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean canSerialize(Class<?> type) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean canSerialize(Class<?> type, AtomicReference<Throwable> cause) {
            return false;
        }

   }
}
```